# Assigning App Item Field value to point to an existing item in Podio using Podio API Importer Service

Tags: .net, api, podio

We are trying to assign the app item field to an item that already exists in podio using a cell on our excel sheet that contains the item's ItemId.

The documentations is as follows:

App:
{

"app_id": The id of one of the referenced apps the sub items should be imported into,

"mappings": The mapping of the fields in the app to, exactly like this operation
}

I have assigned relationships in the past successfully by creating the related items within the importer. However, I am unsure how to or even if it's possible to assign this relationship using an item that is already in Podio. Typically, when not using the import service, I can assign these fields by simply giving them the itemID of the item it's relating to like this:

```
var relationship =HpSource.Field<AppItemField>(fieldId);

relationship.ItemId = 12123212;
```

...... However, it seems the importer wants me to create the new item in code and not simply attach an existing item

Is it possible to do this using the importer service for their .NET API?

Thanks in advance!

(Using Podio.Async)

Comment: which podio library are you using?

Comment: Podio.Async is the only podio related package I have downloaded